# Android Programming: How to make navigation bar fully transparent in Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-navigation-bar

I want to make the navigation bar fully transparent in my app. I have tried the other answers, but they only make the status bar fully transparent and the navigation bar still has a dark half-transparent color. Here is my code:

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**Activity.java:**

```
getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Here is the result I'm trying to get: [goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuNJG.png)

and here is the result I'm currently getting: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjJt0.png)

Is there any way to achieve a fully transparent navigation bar?

Comment: Have you tried using the `FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS` flag?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `<item name="android:android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`  set `android:statusBarColor` to `@android:color/transparent`.

Then add code below:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

If you also want the navigation bar to be translucent, set `android:navigationBarColor` to `@android:color/transparent` and combine the flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION` as well.

Try it may it will work.